# Taylor series of $\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}$ around $x=2$

Tags: taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the Taylor series of $$f(x) = \frac{x}{(x-1)^2}$$ around $x=2$. Since the standard technique of taking and evaluating derivatives leads to crazy expression by the second derivative, I was hoping it would be possible to manipulate the geometric series $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}x^n$ for $|x|<1$. Substituting $(x-2)$ for $x$ gives me $$\frac{1}{1-(x-2)} = \frac{1}{3-x} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(x-2)^n$$ This is where I am stuck. How can I further manipulate this to get my desired function?

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

$$\begin{align}
\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}=-x\frac{-1}{(x-1)^2} &= -x\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x-1}\\
&= -x \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1+(x-2)}\\
&= (-(x-2)-2) \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1+(x-2)}
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have made a slight mistake while replacing $x$ by "$(x-2)$", it should be "$(x+2)$".

Indeed it shows clearly when using an intermediate variable with a different name:

$\phantom{----}$substitute $(x\to 2)$ by $(x=2+u)$ with $(u\to 0)$

$\dfrac 1{1-x}$ becomes $\dfrac 1{1-(u+2)}=\dfrac {1}{-u-1}=\dfrac {-1}{1+u}=\dfrac{-1}{1+(x-2)}$

Now the $x-2$ appears but in the correct expression.

Then you can exploit the derivation trick presented by G.Tony Jacobs

And use $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(2-x)^n\quad$ with a changed sign since we deal with $\dfrac 1{1+u}$ and not $\dfrac 1{1-u}$.

---

Edit: 11/11

$\begin{array}{ll}\displaystyle
f(x) &=\dfrac x{(x-1)^2}=\dfrac{u+2}{(1+u)^2}=-(u+2)\mathrm{\dfrac {d}{du}}\left(\dfrac 1{1+u}\right)=-(u+2)\mathrm{\dfrac {d}{du}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nu^n\right)\\
\\
&\displaystyle\overset{(0)}{=}-(u+2)\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^nnu^{n-1}\\
\\
&\displaystyle\overset{(1)}{=}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg(-(-1)^nnu^{n}-2(-1)^nnu^{n-1}\bigg)\\
\\
&\displaystyle\overset{(2)}{=}\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}-(-1)^nnu^{n}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}2(-1)^n(n+1)u^n\\
\\
&\displaystyle\overset{(3)}{=}2+\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n(n+2)u^{n}\\
\\
&\displaystyle\overset{(4)}{=}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n(n+2)u^{n}
\end{array}$

$(0)$: derivate the innards of the sum term by term

$(1)$: distribute $(u+2)$ inside the sum

$(2)$: split sum into two parts and re-index the second one so it has $u^n$ as a general term.

$(3)$: isolate orphan terms (here this is the term in $u^0$) and regroup the other ones under the sum.

$(4)$: eventually since $2=(-1)^0(0+2)u^0$ we can re-embed it into the sum and start indexing at zero instead of $1$.

*Note: you could have done $(3)$ and $(4)$ in one go, but as a general method, it is better to have separate steps as it happens that some series are not so compliant with orphaned terms.*

Finally if you express the Taylor series with the proper $x$ variable you get:

> $\displaystyle\dfrac x{(x-1)^2}=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}(n+2)(2-x)^n$

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Unfortunately I still don’t know how the derivation trick would help me here, since I am looking for the expansion around $x=2$

Comment: I have written a full solution while explaining each step. As I have said, it is easier to work with the intermediate variable $u$ and replace by $(x-2)$ only at the very end.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now it's clear :)